Unexpected Terminal Output When Running C++ Programs in VSCode with C/C++ extension
I encountered a strange issue when using Visual Studio Code (VSCode) to run C++ programs with the GDB debugger.
When I run a C++ program, beside the normal comments which are highlighted, the terminal sometimes outputs unexpected and seemingly broken strings, and it interferes with the program’s output.. Below is an example output:
PS D:\NL>  & 'c:\Users\me\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.22.11-win32-x64\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe' '--stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-4hl3yf0d.as3' '--stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-rlow4555.xsz' '--stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-pioraos3.gvm' '--pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-chbaoneb.3ex' '--dbgExe=D:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\gdb.exe' '--interpreter=mi'
crosoft-MIEngine-Error-pioraos3.gvm' '--pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-chbaoneb.3ex' '--dbgExe=D:\x5cmsys64\x5cucrt64\x5cbin\x5cgdb.exe' '--interpreter=mi' ;96e10436-01ec-49c4-a7fa-b871c6e5d569Hello World

as:
terminal
The issue appears inconsistently:

Sometimes, the terminal does not show this abnormal output at all, and old abnormal output in the terminal disappears entirely.
Other times, this abnormal output appears after the normal program output (e.g., "Hello World"). In such cases, the program output seems to overwrite portions of the abnormal output, like so:

PS D:\NL>  & 'c:\Users\me\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.22.11-win32-x64\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe' '--stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-4hl3yf0d.as3' '--stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-rlow4555.xsz' '--stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-pioraos3.gvm' '--pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-chbaoneb.3ex' '--dbgExe=D:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\gdb.exe' '--interpreter=mi'
Hello Worldngine-Error-pioraos3.gvm' '--pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-chbaoneb.3ex' '--dbgExe=D:\x5cmsys64\x5cucrt64\x5cbin\x5cgdb.exe' '--interpreter=mi' ;96e10436-01ec-49c4-a7fa-b871c6e5d569 

I'm using the following setup:

Environment:C/C++ extension ms-vscode.cpptools latest version.
launch.json: default g++.exe build active file.
Operating System: Windows (64-bit).

I can't find a clear pattern causing this behavior. My main questions are:

What causes this abnormal output in the terminal when debugging in VSCode?
How can I fix or prevent it from appearing?

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

THe output you show looks just like a command to execute the windows debugger. What exactly do you believe is wrong with it?

vscode is not only outputting the normal command but also adding another comment to the normal command output. I believe this is an abnormal error because I couldn't find similar examples through my searches, and the output is not properly highlighted, which interferes with the program's output.
I have attached a screenshot of the terminal output in my question, where you can see the abnormal output.

OldBoy and @drescherjm look carefully at the commandline. it's truly broken. one of the arguments gets split in the middle and a shell quote is missing where it's broken- both of which are bugs. maybe something to do with conpty/xterm.js/VSC. friendly reminder to read carefully.

@user956918 I suggest you raise a bug ticket. if you do, please add a link here to your ticket.

@starball Thank you! I have raised a bug ticket in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/12477
